# Ocultar página para usuarios no registrados

Tags: wordpress

[image: Página que necesito ocultar]

Necesito ocultar la página editar perfil solo para los usuarios no registrados

Comment: **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos! Revisar [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Usa este plug-in, lo acabo de probar y funciona de maravilla!
 [es.wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu](http://es.wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu)

Para instalarlo:
Te vas al Menu de WP> Apariencia> Menus> y estando ahi seleccionas el elemento(en tu caso PERFIL), te van aparecer 4 opciones adicionales a URL e INICIO, y al final una casilla que dice *"Enable visibility rules"*, la vas a seleccionar y en la parte con los enlaces purpuras solo selecciona la que dice *"Is Logged in"*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo se, pero me gusta mas ponerlo de la manera que esta en mi imagen, he estado mirando los conditional tags, pero no consigo que me desaparezca la página de alli, solo su contenido

Comment: Bueno entonces usa este plug-in, lo acabo de probar y funciona de maravilla!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/

Comment: Lo he instalado y activado, pero no lo localizo en la barra de administracion, ¿me puedes decir como se utiliza?

Comment: Te vas al Menu de WP> Apariencia> Menus> y estando ahi seleccionas el elemento(en tu caso PERFIL), te van aparecer 4 opciones adicionales a URL e INICIO, y al final una casilla que dice "Enable visibility rules", la vas a seleccionar y en la parte con los enlaces  purpuras solo selecciona la que dice "Is Logged in". Ve la imagen: https://i.imgur.com/lzVprlH.png

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido localizar, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @LuisHernandez edita tu respuesta para completarla con la información que hay en los comentarios